# Функция swscanf не находит строку

Tags: c

```
wchar_t buf[] = "12|01234|это я|";
int     nn = 0;
long    nu = 0;
wchar_t ftip[50];
swscanf( buf, L"%u|%lu|%50[^|]||", &nn, &nu, ftip );
```

Почему не работает %50[^|]|?

Comment: @sedoi, а что Вы ожидали ? Регулярных выражений в форматах ? Их там нет.

Comment: @avp, чуть-чуть всё же есть.

Comment: %s *"в официальной доке написано, что scanf умеет только до первого пробела"*

Comment: @lirik90, это для %s. А так можно`scanf("%50[^\n]", str);`, например.

Answer (score 2):

> Почему не работает %50[^|]|?

В MSDN пишут, что scanf умеет воспринимать различные символы-фильтры:

> Reading Undelimited strings
>
> To read strings not delimited by whitespace characters, a set of characters in brackets ([ ]) can be substituted for the s (string) type character. The set of characters in brackets is referred to as a control string. The corresponding input field is read up to the first character that does not appear in the control string. If the first character in the set is a caret (^), the effect is reversed: The input field is read up to the first character that does appear in the rest of the character set.
>
> Note that %[a-z] and %[z-a] are interpreted as equivalent to %[abcde...z]. This is a common scanf function extension, but note that the ANSI standard does not require it.

Причем якобы это работает для всех ф-ций ряда *`scanf`*. Ряд источников из интернета подтверждают, что эта функция (задания шаблона) работает и для `fscanf`, `sscanf` и пр.

Так что действительно надо писать `%50[^|]|`.